# Ajax Add to Cart validation - When customer add more products to cart than the stock quantity is available in Product

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento2.4, quantity, form-validation

When user is adding/increasing quantity than how to we can restrict him ? **He can't add/increase quantity more than available saleable quantity.**

How to we can apply validation for display error message available quantity is not more than this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First find `phtml` file that's used for quantity input and then fetch saleable quantity for product using product object or as per you get.
Once you successfully got product saleable quantity then add that value on quantity input attribute `"maxlength"` like `maxlength="product saleable quantity value"` after that user don't able to increase quantity more than available saleable quantity.

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: I did it as you mentioned but maxlength not working as validation. user can still add more than saleble quantity.

Comment: Please try only "max" attribute inside of "maxlength" I think it is work for you. also please check you properly got product saleable quantity value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in text form field like :

```
... class="required-entry validate-digits-range digits-range-1-20"...
```

This will validate the value to be between 1 and 20.

Comment: can i set this according to saleble quantity of product ?

Comment: of course, you need to set range dynamically " digits-range-<?php echo minQty.'-.'$maxQty ?>"..

Comment: digit range is class or attr of html ?

Comment: Its class name.